# How to use grep to search for an exact word match in TextWrangler

Tags: grep, textwrangler

There is a possibility to search using grep in TextWrangler

I want to find and replace the following word: `bauvol`, but not `bauvolumen`. 
I tried typing `^bauvol$` into the search field but that didn't do the trick, it didn't find anything, although the word is clearly there.

I think it's because, in grep, the `^`and `$`signify start and end of **line**, not a word?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `\b` as word boundaries, as @gromi08 said:

```
\bbauvol\b
```

If you want to copy any portion of this word (so you can replace it, modify it, change the case, etc.) it is usually best to wrap it in `(` and `)` braces so you can reference them in the Replace box:

```
Find:
  (\bbauvol\b)

Replace:
  <some_tag>\1</some_tag>
```

Did you have anything specific you were trying to do with the result once you found it (cut it, duplicate it, etc.)?

Comment: Ok, great, that works. I just wanted to replace it. Is `\b` a grep-specific flag? Or is it RegEx?

Comment: `\b` is a regex, and you can use it with command-line `grep` as well as TextWrangler's built-in `grep`. If you open the TextWrangler User Manual (Help->User Manual), down on page `137` shows other useful things like `\A` (beginning of document/file), `\B` (the opposite of `\b`, so anything NOT a word boundary), `\Z` and `\z` (end of the document, taking special consideration for any extra newlines before the last line).

Answer (score 0):

Use the -w option of grep (see grep [man-page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/OpenSolaris/1/grep).
This option searches for the expression as a word.

Therefore the command will be:

```
cat file.txt | grep -w bauvol
```

And yes, `^` and `$` are for start and end of line.

Comment: Ok, but I am looking for using grep in **TextWrangler**. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have TextWrangler, but maybe `grep '\bbauvol\b'` will do the job. Let me know if it is and I'll edit the answer.